# UNNEST(ARRAY[]) returning a single row with paranthesis

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to flatten a list of strings coming from the UI using the following SQL query

```
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO mydb.temp select unnest(array[:myList])  ", nativeQuery = true)
    public void findrows(
        @Param("myList") List<String> myList) throws MDBServiceException;
```

The result I was getting is this:

```
| id       | 
| -------- | 
| (A01,B01)|
```

Instead I want my result to be like this:

```
| id  | 
| --- | 
| A01 | 
| B01 |
```

I am also trying with `json_array_text_elements` but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve looks like the opposite of flattening a list. You want one insert per element, right?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  mylist has more than 50k values..and all of them should be in different rows and yes, one insert per element in the list into a single row

Comment: Why not pass each `myList` entry separately?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this code is part of an API which will fetch the records inserted and provide another value..implementing each myList separately might give gateway time error

Answer (score 1):

Set returning functions (like unnest) should be used in the FROM clause. And an INSERT statement should always specify the target columns for which values are provided:

```
INSERT INTO mydb.temp (col1, col2, col3)
select c1, c2, c3
from unnest(array[:myList]) as u(c1, c2, c3)
```